# Call function in a DOM <script> source from within an Aurelia spa component

Tags: javascript, .net, model-view-controller, datatable, aurelia

I have a web application, a spa that sits in an MVC page like so

```
<html>
<body and page things> 
<script src="myRootPage/lib/datatables.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="MySPABundle">
</html>
```

In chrome debug console, I can do the following:
`$('#MyElement').dataTable();`

This works successfully.

Now in the spa, I have a component myTable.js which does the following:

```
attached() {
   $('#MyElement').dataTable();
};
```

This throws as datatables is not a function.
For reasons I won't get into, I need to use datatables from the host mvc and not npm install datatables and require from like any other webpack like way.
Is there something I'm missing? How do i import this script or call the function?

Answer (score 0):

So I have found a solution!
When using `window.$('#MyElement').dataTable();`
I would get a webpack window undefined method exception.
But if I use `global.$('#MyElement').dataTable();` I have access to the correct window context. Hope this helps others too!